# How to pass TypedArray into a bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, typed-arrays

Can somebody explain how can we pass a `TypedArray` into a Bundle in Android?
I'm using the `TypedArray` to store some images from `@Drawable` in the resource file and I want to pass that array to a fragment with `setArguments` which accepts a bundle.

code snippet:

```
{
    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Fragment f = new fFragment();

        fImages = (Parcelable)getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.fImages);
        fNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fNames);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putStringArray("name", fNames);
        b.putParcelable("image", fImages);
        sub.setArguments(b);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainFrameLayout, f).commit();
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some code as it seems there is a better way to do that?

Comment: Create a Parcelable object to hold onto that data instead

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the advice, but id tried it and it doesn't fit. when the code gets to the line where you insert the key/value into the bundle it crashes. i will upload the code snippet in a moment

Comment: @Eselfar i added a code snippet for your request

Answer (score 0):

Use `toString()` method for pass Typedarray, have look

```
TypedArray typedArray = null;
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("myArray",typedArray.toString());
```

Comment: That should be obvious, now how do you get it out as a TypedArray?

Comment: get as string but have manually split string and set it in to again in TypedArray.

Comment: @HemantParmar thanks for the suggestion but ihave some doubts here as the typedarray is a collection of integers stored in a binary way. converting it back may not result nice :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the TypeArray. Just pass the resource id to the next Fragment. Then the next Fragment will have to get the TypeArray from the resources.

In Fragment 1

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("TYPE_ARRAY_RES_ID", R.array.fNames);
final Fragment f = new Fragment2();
f.setArguments(b);
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.mainFrameLayout, f)
        .commit();
```

In Fragment 2

```
@ArrayRes int typeArrayRes =  getArguments().getInt("TYPE_ARRAY_RES_ID");
String[] stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(typeArrayRes);
// TODO
```

Comment: With a little minor change the method of passing the resource id solved my issue. 
The issue was that the array is of type int and not string. Thanks.